# Inserting new column with using select and union all

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a product table.

```
Create Table tblProduct
(
    ID int,
    Project_No int,
    OrderDate date
)

insert into tblProduct values (2580, 100, '2012-01-13')
insert into tblProduct values (2581, 101, '2012-01-21')
insert into tblProduct values (2582, 102, '2012-03-04')
insert into tblProduct values (2583, 103, '2012-02-14')
```

I need to combine with months and give an output as follows based on the order date (but i don't want to display in output result):

```
Jan   2580   100
Feb   2581   101
Mar   2582   102
```

But I don't have separate table for month.

So, I think I have to use `SELECT.....UNION ALL` to achieve what I want.

But I don't know how to use. Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: What's the criteria to assign a month to the rows in your table?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: @danielsepulvedab, it have to combine based on order date. Can I too omit the criteria and just simply join?

Comment: @marc_s I added the tag, I am using sql server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
SELECT
  DATENAME(month, OrderDate), ID, Project_No
FROM tblProduct
```

Comment: Thanks @danielsepulvedab  Any other way I can use with UNION ALL ? Lets say I don't have any criteria to join, just simply combine with month ('Jan'  , 'Feb' ,etc) to tblProduct and I have to use those keywords ?

Comment: `UNION ALL` is used when you need to add more rows with the same structure to your result set, this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you can get the desired output  without using the UNION ALL operator.

Executed your queries into my SSMS2014

```
create table tblProduct(
    ID int,
    Project_No int,
    OrderDate datetime
)

insert into tblProduct
values
(2581,100,'2012-01-13'),
(2581,101,'2012-01-21'),
(2582,102,'2012-03-04'),
(2583,103,'2012-02-14')

select * from tblProduct
```

[image]

```
select 
    LEFT(DATENAME(month,OrderDate),3) as DateColumn,
    ID,
    Project_No 
from tblProduct
```

[image]

More Reading about [DATENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql)

Comment: Can we use SELECT...UNION ALL keywords if I don't have any particular criteria to join. Just simply combine like 'Jan | 2580 | 100 , and so on...' ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your help. I've finally figured it out and achieve exactly what I want.

```
SELECT '1'As Mnth, ID as ProductID,Project_No,OrderDate
from T2
where month(OrderDate)=1
UNION 
select '2'As Mnth, ID as ProductID,Project_No,OrderDate
from T2
where month(OrderDate) =2
UNION 
select '3'As Mnth, ID as ProductID,Project_No,OrderDate
from T2
where month(OrderDate) =3
UNION 
select '4'As Mnth, ID as ProductID,Project_No,OrderDate
from T2
where month(OrderDate) =4
```

Here, I don't have to create a separate table for Month, and also I don't need any table to create in advance , to get the result.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgrC6.jpg)